# start postgreSQL Server and psql via batch file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, command-line

I would like to start the postgreSQL Server and psql via batch file.
By hand I would use:

```
"K:\db\pgsql\bin\pg_ctl.exe" -D "K:\db\pgsql\data" start
"K:\db\pgsql\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -W
```

This I saved as a batch file. Excecuting the file, the server is started and psql as well. But if I like to quit psql with `\q` the command line seems to be stucked and I can´t stop the server properly or do something else like use pg_dump for example.
Is there something wrong about my batch file?

Comment: Ihe `psql -U postgres -W -d database1` command is expecting characters from stdin. Which it does not get, so it waits forever.

Comment: @ wildplasser but without batch file- entering each command by hand- it is working well